# How to merge nested Maps in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to merge values from two maps in Kotlin, but I can't seem to find a solution online to do so. For example, I have these two Map Objects that have nested maps as shown below.

first: `{settings={exit={exitMessage=message0}}, 2=2}`

second: `{settings={exit={differentMessage=message1, secondMessage=message2}}, 2=zebra}`

As you can see, there are some keys that are the same(like `settings` and `exit`), but sometimes the keys are different. I'm wondering how I can merge the two Map objects so the end result is like

`{settings={exit={exitMessage=message0, differentMessage=message1, secondMessage=message2}}, 2=zebra}`

We can't simply "add" the two maps together, because Kotlin will override the Map objects

For example, if we add the two objects up above, as `first + second`, the end result will just be

`{settings={exit={differentMessage=message1, secondMessage=message2}}, 2=zebra}`

as the `exit` map in second takes priority over the `exit` map object in first.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out right now. In kotlin, when you add two Map Objects together(for example, if I add `first` and `second`), if the keys are the same(in my example, the key is `settings`), Kotlin chooses the `second` maps value at key `settings` to be in the merged map

Comment: Oh oops I read the wrong bit. Ignore what I just said.

Comment: Are the maps mutable? It would be a lot easier if they were.

Comment: Yes, the maps are mutable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try flattening both maps first:

```
settings.exit.exitMessage=message0
2=2
```

```
settings.exit.differentMessage=message1
settings.exit.secondMessage=message2
2=zebra
```

Then after merging the maps you end up with this:

```
settings.exit.exitMessage=message0
settings.exit.differentMessage=message1
settings.exit.secondMessage=message2
2=zebra
```

And then just rebuild the map again by exploding the keys.

Full code sample here: https://pl.kotl.in/p9BaUVOF3

#### Flattening a map

```kotlin
fun flatten(source: Map<String, Any>, target: HashMap<String, Any>, prefix: String = "") {
    for (entry in source) {
        var fullKey = if (prefix.length > 0) prefix + "." + entry.key else entry.key
        if (entry.value is Map<*, *>) {
            flatten(entry.value as Map<String, Any>, target, fullKey)
            continue
        }
        target.put(fullKey, entry.value)
    }
}
```

#### Exploding a flattened map

```kotlin
fun explode(source: Map<String, Any>, target: HashMap<String, Any>) {
    for (entry in source) {
        var targetMap = target
        var keySegments = entry.key.split(".")
        // Rebuild the map
        for (keySegment in keySegments.dropLast(1)) {
            if (targetMap.containsKey(keySegment)) {
                var value = targetMap.get(keySegment)
                if (value is Map<*, *>) {
                    targetMap = value as HashMap<String, Any>
                    continue
                }
            }
            var newNestedMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
            targetMap.put(keySegment, newNestedMap)
            targetMap = newNestedMap
        }
        // Put values into it
        targetMap.put(keySegments.last(), entry.value)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I flatten the maps? Also, what do you mean by exploding the keys

Comment: I don't know for Kotlin in particular but in general you can flatten a map by traversing it recursively and storing the values you find into another map using keys that are composed from keys from the source map. I'll try updating the answer a bit. Exploding a map is the reverse process.

Comment: I added a hint on flattening to the answer (coding on my mobile though).

Comment: @Mkim175 I've updated the answer and included a working code sample.